# Product of an holomorphic function and other functions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic functions is true that $f\bar {g}$ is holomorphic? 
I think that it's false. I take $f=1$ and $g=z$. It's correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.